# how to install qtp demo version for second time

Tags: qtp

Is there any way to install a free trial version of the software in a same computer? I had qtp 12.00 trial version and the date got expired. I need to be installed again. I tried it by creating a new user and installing from that user. But that method dint help me. Do anyone have any idea. I have installed a application in my machine in which if I change the OS I ll lose my application.

Thanks

Comment: You gotta format the machine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is getting dangerously close to asking how to crack a piece of commercial software. You've had your free trial.

Comment: Which company do you work for? Surely they can afford licenses?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this forum encourages this type of question!

Trial version is only for evaluation purpose. You should buy new license to use it further if you really like it!

You can use Selenium for your automation if it is web based - it is FREE & open source!!
Or VBScript to automate any windows based application.